# callback url with HTTP Post not working using ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, c#-5.0

There is a frontend application developed using angularjs which uses ui.router for managing the routing functionality within the frontend application. User open the URL (`https://www.testsite.com`) and clicks the login button which redirects him to another application (authentication app) with url : `https://www.testauthentication.com/sign`. Post successful login process, authentication provider send back the user by sending a POST request on a callback url (`https://www.testsite.com/account/processing`).

There is a route configured for the callback url (`https://www.testsite.com/account/processing`) as shown below, but the below route never triggers. But when I try to open the same callback url via browser, it works. In this case it shows that HTTP method is GET.

router.js:

```
.state("account.processingauth", {
  url: "/processing?uid&uidSignature&signatureTimestamp&state",
  templateUrl: "/modules/account/processing/processing.html",
  controller: "ProcessingCtrl",
  resolve: {
    /////Code to handle the resole methods
  },

})
```

[image]

Can anyone help me here with your guidance how to handle this scenario?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance on how to handle this scenario with some code samples?. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've ruled out a bad ui-router state configuration, because you can successfully access the state via the browser address bar.

So, your focus should be the interfacing with the 3rd party authentication app.

Use your browser's dev tools NETWORK tab to confirm the POST is properly including/formatting the return URL according to the requirements of the 3rd party authentication app.

If the interface is wired correctly, then confirm that the 3rd party authentication app is working properly. Confirm whether the browser's address bar changes in response to the 3rd party app's redirect. You might gain insight by running FIDDLER to see what the 3rd party app is returning to the browser.

Also, you might modify your question to include the block of code that makes the POST to the 3rd party app.

(Note:  I do not have enough points to add this as a comment)